# How to Select current element in jQuery.Treeview after jQuery.load(html)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I have HTML code like this within **sample.html** file:

```
<ul id='topics' class='filetree'>
<li><span class='folder'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=#'>Topics</a></span>
<ul>
<li><span class='folder'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=1'>Topic 1</a></span>
<ul>
<li><span class='file'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=1.1'>Topic 1.1</a></span></li>
<li><span class='file'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=1.2'>Topic 1.2</a></span></li>
<li><span class='file'><a href='?Lang=en&TopicID=1.3'>Topic 1.3</a></span></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Using **JQuery.load** I load html file in order to generate Treeview

```
<div id="LtrLeftContent">
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         $('#LtrLeftContent').load('sample.html', function () {
                $("#topics").treeview();
         });
     </script>
</div>
```

**1st question:** How to find out current node text. when click on a tree node ?
**2nd question:** How to find out parent + current node text. when click on a tree node ?
**3rd question:** How to set CSS into node. When click on a tree node ?

After few try I get the current element

```
$("li span").click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Full code like bellow

```
<div id="LtrLeftContent">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
            $('#LtrLeftContent').load('sample.html', function () {  
                $("#topics").treeview();  
                $("li span").click(function () {  
                    alert($(this).text());  
                });  
            });                 
        </script>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).text());
    console.log($(e.currentTarget).closest('.folder').text());

    // didn't quite get your last question
    // but this is how you would manipulate 
    // the current elements parent list item
    $(e.currentTarget).parents('li').css({
        'background-color': '#000'
    });
    return false;
});
```